# Wrong list price shown in magento

Tags: magento

I am new in magento eCommerce. I have this problem:

[image: Wrong price]

here, ￥27 is shown in as the price (in the store page). Where as, in the product page, the actual price is shown:  ￥27,300

What might be the possible reason for this. I searched over internet and stackoverflow but couldn't find anything.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this myself. This is how I did it:

I first looked at the template path hint from the magento -> configuration -> debug. Then I got to know from which template page is the price shown. Then, there; I changed:

```
<p class="listprices"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency(number_format($_product->getPrice(),2));  ?> </p>
```

this to

```
<p class="listprices"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice());  ?> </p>
```

Problem solved :)